# Is it possible to add a state to a styled react component like this?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

```
import React from "react"
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Segment = styled.div`
    background-color: #1070ff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff33;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    &:first-of-type {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
    &:last-child {
        border-radius: 0px 0px 35px 35px;
    }
`

export default Segment;
```

I know I can create functions in this file, but is it possible to have a state for `Segment` while it's a styled component, or would I have to make it into a class?

Basically I just plan on adding a handleClick method to change the bgColor but I'm unsure if I have to restructure the component to be able to add state.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `state` cannot be added to a styled component only `props` can be passed. But a styled component can be used inside any other class-based or functional component. What you would do is pass the color as prop to a styled component from a React Component and then you can export the React Component as follows:

```js
// If a color has been passed from props use that, if not use a default color value
const Segment = window.styled.div`
 background-color: ${props => (props.color ? props.color : "#1070ff")};
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff33;
 width: 400px;
 height: 70px;
`

class SegmentClass extends React.Component {
 state = { color: "#000" }

 // If the color is black change to blue otherwise change to black
 changeColor = () => {
  this.setState((state, props) => {
   const { color } = state
   const newColor = color === "#000" ? "#1070ff" : "#000"
   return { color: newColor }
  })
 }

 render() {
  return <Segment color={this.state.color} onClick={this.changeColor} />
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SegmentClass />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Now you can export the SegmentClass which will provide the required functionality

Comment: I would use callback inside `setState` just to be sure that you are referencing to the valid current state. +1

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much.  I'll try this out later!